# Extracting number of insertion and deletions of git diff using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I'm using `gif diff --shortstat filename` to get the number of lines changed in my files. The output example is as follows:

```
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Now I want to use that command with `sed` and extract the **number** of insertion and deletions only, in this case `1` and `1`.

I'm using `sed` to match and extract the groups but all I get is the same text from the `git` command again. My command is as follows (trying to get only the insertion lines number).

```
sed "s/\([0-9]+\) insertion/\1/"
```

So, a complete execution will be like:

```
$ git diff --shortstat filename | sed 's/\([0-9]+\) insertion/\1/'
> 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

What I need to change to get this to work or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You may use `sed "s/.* \([0-9][0-9]*\) insertion.*/\1/"`

Comment: I don't get it. Your expected output looks exactly the same as the input except for a leading `> `.Or is the text after `a complete execution will be like` not your expected output? If so - what IS the expected output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This helped extracting the insertion number, thank you! Is there a way to do another regex group for the deletion?

Comment: Use `sed "s/.* \([0-9][0-9]*\) insertion.* \([0-9][0-9]*\) deletion.*/\1, \2/"`. Annubhava's solution won't help if you have more than 9 diffs.

Comment: Good point Wiktor, adding space solves it, check edited answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `sed` command to extract both insertion and deletion number:

```
git diff --shortstat filename | 
sed -E 's/.* ([0-9]+) insertion.* ([0-9]+) deletion.*/\1,\2/'
```

This will produce a comma delimited pair of numbers e.g.

```
1,1
```

Comment: If that's all you need then `awk '{print $4,$6}'` would do it.

Comment: I think `awk -v OFS=, '$5 ~ /^insertion/ && $7 ~ /^deletion/ {print $4, $6}'` would be similar as we need to make sure we are extracting numbers before `insertion` and `deletion` keywords.

Comment: Given the sample input in the question, it's the same output either way. If the input can be something other than what the OP showed us then maybe your sed script won't work either (e.g. if insertion can exist on it's own without deletion).